# What antimicrobial can be readily synthesized in a school laboratory for a project on antimicrobial resistance?

Tags: organic-chemistry, safety, chemical-biology, drugs

I am currently a student studying at a high school hoping to do a project on antimicrobial compound synthesis to use in investigating antimicrobial resistance in *E. coli* strains. I am hoping to synthesize an antimicrobial to use in *in vitro* testing.

I have looked at sulfonamides, but the involvement of benzene in some of the procedures (for example, in the synthesis step of 3-amino-5-methylisoxazole of sulfamethoxazole), is banned because of health and safety regulations in high school labs.

Is there an alternative for a compound that could be synthesized with high school lab chemicals under guidance with maybe one or two external orders of specific compounds?

Comment: Is benzene just a solvent? You could try simply replacing it with toluene…

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately benzene is suggested in the paper as both the solvent and something used to recrystallize the residue formed from the procedure in the end, so it might not be possible.The paper also said ether could be used as a solvent.

Comment: I am pretty sure toluene could be used as solvent instead of benzene.

Comment: The point is that is not clear if the project is about chemistry or somewhat biology. I do not see why a project on antimicrobial resistance involves the synthesis of the antimicrobial agent. Not that I am against a multidisciplinary approach, but perhaps you should focus on the antimicrobial resistance in E. Coli and test different antibiotics

Comment: Well... that's tougher. Is it possible for you or for someone to test the recrys with toluene before committing to the full synthesis?

Comment: I do not think that it is possible. Thank you for the suggestion.
Thank you for your reflections on the aims of my project too, but it was simply a nice idea to test what I've synthesized on the E. Coli K12 strains as a proof of concept that it works. I have also tried to expand my idea to include multiple variants of antimicrobial compounds including testing Sulfamethoxazole/Trimethoprim mixes in a 20:1 ratio to see if it would be more effective compared using them alone. However, that also seems too ambitious due to the limitations of a school laboratory on certain compounds and also cost.

Comment: Metronidazole perhaps

Comment: Thank you for your reply, would you possible have details concerning synthesis of metronidazole...? I'm quite new to synthesis and the only paper I can find is its synthesis from ethylenediamine.

Comment: Metronidazole can be prepared from the commercially available 2-methylimidazole (100g for £24 from Sigma-Aldrich) in 2 steps. Nitration https://patents.google.com/patent/US4209631A/en then reaction with chloroethanol (£30 for 100g from Sigma Aldrich)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will check the patent out and check with relevant teachers to hopefully see if this can be done.

Comment: If the nitration is a problem then the 5-nitro-2-methylimidazole is also commercially available, and fairly cheap

Comment: @Waylander I think metronidazole would work well. Thank you for the suggestion. On a side note, would you have any data regarding the synthesis of Trimethoprim..? Hoping to synthesize that too hopefully but the molecule probably looks too complicated. I have found multiple patents describing various different methods of synthesis of intermediates, but it is really hard to organize into a single coherent synthesis sequence.

Comment: @CrownEther  The syntheses of trimethoprim I have seen involved the use of acrylonitrile which is a fairly nasty allergen and suspect carcinogen. I suspect that may be too much for a high school lab.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will remove that from my list.

Comment: @Waylander would you also have the steps regarding the second step of the reaction for metronidazole regarding chloroethanol? Deciding on asking a professional before purchasing the document that probably details the reaction https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00764821.

Comment: I have never done this chemistry, but a search of the patent literature yields a method whereby 2-Me-5-nitroimidazole is heated with an excess of chloroethanol in the absence of solvent.  See example 1 of https://patents.google.com/patent/US2944061A/en   Chloroethanol is a hazardous material by inhalation or skin contact. Take appropriate precautions.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will be adequately protected.

Answer (score 2):

There are many [common antimicrobials](https://academic.oup.com/pch/article/11/3/169/4560373) in use, and one that *might* be comparatively easy to sythesize would be a [quaternary ammonium compound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternary_ammonium_cation). For example, [this patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/EP0791575A1/en) claims the "reaction is carried out in water."

That said, the reactants and the resulting antibacterial might have intrinsic environmental and health hazards.

BTW, why not investigate some traditional antimicrobial compounds used for food preservation, such as sodium chloride, calcium chloride, acetic acid, or various sugars? No synthesis is needed. And *must* you use *E. coli*, or can you investigate other organisms, such as fungi, that cause food spoilage?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would prefer using *E.coli* because it links to a previous project I have done, but that seems like a good idea to consider doing in the future too. 
This project would also explore the mechanism of action of the drug on the bacteria, as an example sulfamethoxazol blocks the biosynthetic pathway of folic acid in bacteria., which is quite a specific and interesting topic to learn and write about.
It just would be quite fascinating and be a valuable experience to synthesize it yourself and see it have an action on bacteria based on theory.